# What is pronounciation of ConTeXt

Tags: context

How should I pronounce ConTeXt? In TeX and LaTeX x is χ so it is TeΧ and LaTeΧ. However the t after X make such pronounciation in ConTeXt difficult.

Comment: It depends on context!  :-P

Comment: The 'eχt' combination actually occurs naturally in Dutch, so be careful what you call difficult. I'll grant you 'difficult to learn', though. ;-)

Comment: Pronouncing it as "contekt" would be similar to the English word "contact." So at least in this simplification, I don't think the "kt" combination is at all difficult for a native English speaker.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AFAIK, just like the English word "context" (may be with some Dutch accent to match Hans' `;)`).

Comment: So the rule is that TeX is pronounce as TeX at the end of word in TeX community?

Comment: Iirc, ‘TeXpert’ is pronounced ‘teχpert’, not ‘tekspert’.  So the convention isn’t always to match the similar English word.

Comment: I don't think there is a general rule (AFAIK, there is no official pronouncation for LaTeX either).

Comment: @Peter If you read the TeXbook, you’ll know that you’re not a TeXpert at all but a TeXnician.

Comment: @jleedev: sadly, I’m neither — I started the book, but never finished it…