# What is the correct pronunciation of TeX and LaTeX?

Tags: tex-general, latex-misc

Is it tex(tech)?
Or
Is it tex(like touch)?

Lay-TeX?
or
La-TeX?

Should I use TeX pronunciation in LaTeX?

Comment: see last line in http://www.latex-project.org/intro.html

Comment: What about ConTeXt? The final “t” is for “tricky”.

Comment: @rberaldo: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5406/what-is-pronounciation-of-context

Comment: @Caramdir thank you! I think the Hans Hagen should put it in the manual, just for the sake of tradition.

Comment: TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt… You can listen to Donald Knuth pronouncing them in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HuwiBPLV3A). (Note how LaTeX is pronounced twice in a row with 2 different pronunciation — between 0:14 and 0:18.)

Comment: The anciant greek word technē sounds like /té.kʰnɛː/, why doesn't TeX sound like /tek(ʰ)/?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Let the creators of TeX and LaTeX answer:

Donald Knuth wrote in the first chapter of his *TeXbook*:

> English words like ‘technology’ stem
>   from a Greek root beginning with the
>   letters τεχ...; and this same Greek
>   word means *art* as well as
>   technology. Hence the name TeX, which
>   is an uppercase form of τεχ.
>
> Insiders pronounce the χ of TeX as a
>   Greek chi, not as an ‘x’, so that TeX
>   rhymes with the word blecchhh. It’s
>   the ‘ch’ sound in Scottish words like
>   *loch* or German words like *ach*; it’s a
>   Spanish ‘j’ and a Russian ‘kh’. When
>   you say it correctly to your computer,
>   the terminal may become slightly
>   moist.

Leslie Lamport wrote in the first chapter of his book *LaTeX: A document Preparation System*:

> One of the hardest things about LaTeX
>   is deciding how to pronounce it.This
>   is also one of the few things I'm not
>   going to tell you about LaTeX, since
>   pronunciation is best determined by
>   usage, not fiat. TeX is usually
>   pronounced *teck*, making *lah*-teck,
>   and *lay*-teck the logical choices;
>   but language is not always logical, so
>   *lay*-tecks is also possible.

Comment: a long time ago, in an intro to latex presented at a decus symposium by lamport himself, he said when asked this question, "anything but L.A.TeX".  (in other words, don't pronounce the first two letters as separate syllables.)

Comment: Great answer. Another interesting quote by Knuth is mentioned in footnote 1 on page 1 of [lshort](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf), I think this quote would add to your answer even more. (I couldn't find the quote in the "German Wikipedia" right away though ...)

Comment: @doncherry: thanks for the quote. I, however, was unable to find the source in the German Wikipedia, so I decided not to add the quote to my answer until I (or someone else) can find the source.

Comment: One should note, however, that the Greek χ (chi) is pronounced (at least by the very few Greek people I've met) closer to the English word 'he' than to the German 'ach', so I would question whether Knuth's explanation is fully consistent with modern Greek pronunciation.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: There seem to be two pronunciations of χ in modern greek depending on the context. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_(letter)#Modern_Greek): "In Modern Greek, it has two distinct pronunciations: In front of high or front vowels (/e/ or /i/) it is pronounced as a voiceless palatal fricative [ç], as in German ich or like the h in some pronunciations of the English words hew and human. In front of low or back vowels (/a/, /o/ or /u/) and consonants, it is pronounced as a voiceless velar fricative ([x]), as in German ach."

Comment: @doncherry Apologies for resurrecting this question/answer, but [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskussion:TeX#Aussprache) appears to contain the quote referenced in lshort. Unfortunately, it is simply a quoted response to an email, so it may have been fabricated (probably unlikely?), but I think that that is the quote referred to.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: but *modern* Greek is entirely beside the point.  We don't trace our word "technology" back to *modern* Greek—we trace it back to *ancient* Greek. Unfortunately it is not as easy as we might like to determine the correct (ancient) pronunciation of Greek words, but scholars claim to have a pretty good idea based on things like poetry.

Comment: Nice, though the Spanish 'j' pronunciation doesn't have anything to do, it's sound is very different. In Spanish the letters that sound like this are the "K" and "C" (at the end of the word).

Comment: How could Lamport not have an opinion of what the right way is to pronouce at least the _La_ in LaTeX? It's _his own_ name, I guess he knows how to pronounce it :D

Answer (score 39):

Using the IPA, it is /ˈleɪtɛk/, /ˈleɪtɛx/, /ˈlɑːtɛx/, or /ˈlɑːtɛk/.

**Resources:**

[Pronouncing "LaTeX" on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX#Pronouncing_and_writing_.22LaTeX.22)

> LaTeX is usually pronounced /**ˈlɑːtɛk**/ or /**ˈleɪtɛk**/ in English (that is, not with the /ks/ pronunciation English speakers normally associate with X, but with a /k/). The characters T, E, X in the name come from capital Greek letters tau, epsilon, and chi, as the name of TeX derives from the Greek: τέχνη (skill, art, technique); for this reason, *TeX's creator Donald Knuth promotes a pronunciation of /ˈtɛx/ (tekh)* (that is, with a voiceless velar fricative as in Modern Greek, similar to the last sound of the German word "Bach", the Spanish "j" sound, or as ch in loch). Lamport, on the other hand, has said he does not favor or discourage any pronunciation for LaTeX.

Comment: As a linguistics student, I highly appreciate your IPA, to make it even better, you could/should add either slashes /.../ or brackets [...] around it. Your quote went with the slashes, which indicate phonemic transcription. That seems appropriate here.

Comment: @doncherry Thank you for the suggestion, I have added the slashes. I am actually learning the IPA at the moment as I have become interested in linguistics, particularly phonetics and phonology, so any good advice such as yours is highly appreciated.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'm sure you know it already, but in case you don't, you should check out the [`tipa`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tipa) package for IPA in LaTeX.

Comment: @doncherry I do, thank you. I am currently working on typesetting a short phrasal dictionary so I use it a lot.

Answer (score 27):

I think that it's better to find out what Knuth has to say in the matter... [Listen!!!](http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/media/conferences/tug-2010/Don-Knuth/) :D

Oh, and watch the whole presentation. It is definitely worth it.

Comment: (pronunciation at 13:40)

Comment: Love the digs at Steve Jobs and Apple. Throughout the presentation!

Comment: Pronounced La-Tech - https://youtu.be/8HuwiBPLV3A?t=16

Comment: @YangshunTay or Lay-Tech, "the author never did decide how to pronounce it."

Answer (score 16):

Knuth answers this in the TeXbook: it's "teccch" (a gutteral sound, like in German or Russian or Hebrew, or of course Greek) not "teks" or "tetch".  According to the [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-latexpronounce), there is no official pronunciation for LaTeX, but I often hear "lay-TeX" or (of course) "lay-teks" for humorous reasons.  I prefer "lah-TeX", as in "Lamport", but I'm pedantic.

Answer (score 3):

TeX actually stands for tau-epsilon-chi and the 'X' is therefore pronounced like the 'ch' in German, i.e. by breathing out through half closed mouth (I can't explain it better). It's sounds similar to the 'tech' in 'technique'.

The [TeX Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX) says:

> TeX (/ˈtɛx/ as in Greek, but often pronounced /tɛk/ in English) 
>   ...
>   'ch' like in 'loch'

LaTeX is pronounced *lah-tech* by most German speakers (like me) but in English it is often pronounced *lay-tech*. IMHO that is because it is the natural pronounced of that languages.

Comment: "breathing out through half closed **mouse**"!!! I'm sure you _can't_ explain it better.

Comment: Reading through [Wikipedia's description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_velar_fricative#Features) I wonder, how I can speak at all. Seems way too complicated ;-).

Comment: Incidentally, 'LOL' is now in the Oxford English Dictionary.  It's a sad day.

Comment: Martin, which German "ch"? There's Bach and there's Brecht. The different sources seem to be contradicting each other. The above quotes list the Scottish "loch" but on http://www.latex-project.org/intro.html the instructions compare it with "Brecht". These are different sounds for the ch, at least for a German speaker.

Comment: @teylyn: According to Wikipedia, it is IPA [x], as in German Bach. See also the entry on [χ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_%28letter%29).

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://www.infoq.com/interviews/lamport-latex-paxos-tla/), in the answer to the third question, Leslie Lamport pronounces TeX and LaTeX as `tek` and `lay-tek` respectively, although @gonazalo-medina mentioned a very good reference and I also personally prefer `lah-tek`.

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to suggest a probably unpopular alternative: "latex" /ˈleɪtɛks/. Like the substance. Let it stand for whatever Greek letters it may: I'm not reading it in Greek, so that's irrelevant. Spell it like an existing word and you only invite a reader to read it like an existing word.

Ultimately, I'd posit that it's not *that* important as long as people understand you.

(Also, SQL is not "sequel" and "arXiv" is not "ar-kh-iv" (and *definitely* not "archive").)

Comment: I agree. I actually know some (modern) Greek, but the tongue-in-cheek pronunciation is, in my humble opinion, the one implicitly mandated by Leslie Lamport, which coincides with the English word for rubber, thus implying elasticity and flexibility of LaTeX over its mother(-tongue) TeX.

Comment: SQL = Ask you well.

Comment: I concur with Leslie Lamport that the pronunciation should be dictated (haha) not by fiat (founder or prominent person says) but by usage ie how people pronounce it. I hope more people come around to this practical and simpler idea. This is the same with English words and pronunciation which has made it successful compared to German which is more prescriptive (fiat)