# How to pronounce `TeX Live`?

Tags: texlive

I am not a native English speaker. So I am confused whether `TeX Live` should be pronounced as **[tek liv]** or **[tek laiv]**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "laiv" (to use your phonetic version) so that it sounds the same as "alive" - it's a metaphor from broadcasting I believe - programmes that go out "live" instead of pre-recorded.

Comment: @Thruston, thank you for your tips and explanations.

Comment: You're welcome - everyday I am impressed by how well non-native speakers use my mother tongue!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the pronounce of "TeX", see question [What is the correct pronunciation of TeX and LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17502/16967). Pronunciation is /tɛx/ or /tɛk/.

"Live" is the plain English word "live" pronounced as an *adjective*, not as verb, see
question [The pronunciation of the word “Live”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/1059).
Pronunciation is /laɪv/ ([Oxford Learners Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/live2_1)).

Comment: You might like to make it clear that you mean "pronounced as *an* adjective" and not "to rhyme with *adjective*"... :-)

Comment: According to google the pronunciation is "teks·live" - https://imgur.com/IX05x2n