# Cross partial derivatives with LaTeX

Tags: equations

I'm trying to write something simple:

[image]

Not quite sure how to write out the second term (from the left) in LaTeX. Any suggestions please?

Comment: `\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \biggl( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \biggr) = ...`, performed inside a math environment.  p.s and while pronounced like "Latek`, it is actually spelled with a final "X", as in "LaTeX".

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes it's not pronounced like "Latek" as far as I know... But I think that's what is acceptable for an English speaker :)

Comment: @Skillmon It's pronounced _lah_-teck or _lay_-teck.

Comment: @hooy since the X is not an X but a greek `\chi` it should be pronounced like a greek `\chi` which is not pronounced 'ck' as far as I know, but I totally understand if it's not pronounced that way (as a German I don't pronounce it correct, too, most of the time).

Comment: @Skillmon I'm very aware, I just know [Leslie Lamport himself wrote about this in this book _LaTeX: A document Preparation System_](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17509/30280).

Comment: @hooy so what Lamport wrote is basically: "People pronounce TeX the wrong way, so it is logically to pronounce LaTeX the wrong way, but I do not force anybody to any pronunciation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \, \partial x}
    = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \biggl( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \biggr)
  %  = \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right)
    = (f_x)_y
    = f_{xy}
    = \partial_{yx} f
\]

\end{document}
```

There is a difference in the spacing between using a `\biggl(`...`\biggr)` and `\left(`...`\right)` pair. Your choice, although the former is preferred.

Comment: Thanks guys....works! I'm very new to this...and don't use it often enough to internalize it. Thanks again!