# Crossed partial derivatives

Tags: math-mode, macros, symbols

Note that this is a different question from [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371856/cross-partial-derivatives-with-latex).

That aside, I was unable to find the markup for writing something like this:
[image: crossed derivative]

As visible, I require the partial symbol to have a line across it.

I would also appreciate it if someone could mention the markup for a crossed normal derivative, too, as a bonus.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the warm welcome!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Comment: @Teepeemm - I've voted to re-open this posting as it is about more than looking up a symbol on the detexify site. A usable answer to the OP's query also requires pointing out the need to "wrap" the text-mode `\dh` macro in a `\text` or `\textup` directive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % for "\dh" macro
\usepackage{amsmath}     % for "\textrm" macro
\newcommand{\crpartial}{\textup{\rmfamily\dh}}
\begin{document}
\[
dS \ge \frac{\crpartial q}{T}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Uhm, maybe `\textup`? Otherwise the symbol will change e.g. in a theorem. Alternatively `\textit` from the very beginning, such that the symbol looks slanted no matter what. (On a personal note: as a theoretical physicist I _hate_ this notation... `:-)`)

Comment: @campa - Great suggestion to employ `\textup`. I've updated the code shown in the answer above.

Comment: @William R. Ebenezer If you wonder where to find the right symbols, you may try (http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) works quite well on your example.

Comment: What does the `\dh` do? And why is `\textup` better than `\text`? Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: @AndréC `\dh` draws the symbol. `\textup`makes sure it always appears identical inpendently from the context.

Comment: @AndréC Indeed, `\dh`  is in text mode.

Comment: As far as I know, `\dh` is (i) a symbol that’s still used in modern Icelandic and (ii) a symbol used in phonetics.

Comment: Thanks for the really prompt answer! Me being curious: I wonder if your profile pic is of Jabba the Hutt?

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer - Indeed, it's a picture of my illustrious, much misunderstood, and gratuitously maligned ancestor. People tell me that, as I grow older, the family resemblance is becoming more and more evident. I couldn't be more proud. :-)

Comment: @Mico makes sense! Good day ;)

Comment: Sorry for bothering, but on second thoughts `\textup` changes the shape but not the series. If the macro, for whatever reason, is in a piece set in `\sffamily` the result will be a sans-serif character `:-)` I guess it's safer to do `\textup{\textrm{\dh}}`. Either that or stuff like `\textup{\rmfamily\dh}`, or `\textrm{\upshape\dh}` or other possible permutations...

Comment: @campa - Thanks for noticing this additional issue. I've changed `\textup{\dh}` to `\textup{\rmfamily\dh}` in the definition of the `\crpartial` macro.

Comment: @Mico Erm... the answer has `\textrm{\rmfamily\dh}`. Shouldn't `\textup` be in the place of `\textrm`?

Comment: @frougon - Good catch!

Answer (score 4):

If you're happy with U+00F0 LATIN SMALL LETTER ETH, that is, ð, then you can define it as a math symbol. I used italic, that seems more appropriate.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{toneitalic}{T1}{\familydefault}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cpartial}{\mathord}{toneitalic}{"F0}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
dS\ge\frac{\cpartial q}{T}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The slot number `"F0` is not a coincidence, as the T1 encoding tries to be as consistent with Latin-1 as possible. Anyway, in order to check, I did from the command line

```
latexdef dh
```

to get

```latex
\dh:
macro:->\T1-cmd \dh \T1\dh
```

Hmm, what should we ask for? With some background in the innards of LaTeX

```
latexdef 'T1\dh'
```

is the right thing to ask for:

```latex
\T1\dh:
\char"F0
```

You can also cross `\partial`. The following works with CM fonts, and can be adapted to other fonts. Not really good in `\scriptscriptstyle`; some work is needed in case.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cross@partial}{\mathpalette\cross@@partial\relax}
\newcommand{\cross@@partial}[2]{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{%
    \raisebox{-0.05\height}{%
      \makebox[0.5\width][l]{%
        \rotatebox[origin=l]{30}{$\m@th#1\mathchar'26$}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\cpartial}{\partial\cross@partial}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
dS\ge\frac{\cpartial q}{T}\quad\scriptstyle\cpartial
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]